# settings preferences key not retained iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to set a key in `NSUserDefaults`.  The console log shows the key `auto_reset_switch` set to "YES" when I register the defaults.  However, when I later read the defaults, the auto_reset_switch key is "0".  I have tried setting the key as a `BOOL` or as a `NSString` but it makes no difference.  I am following the text in the book "iOS Programming Big Nerd Ranch Guide 4th edition."  What am I doing wrong?

Here is appDelegate.h:

```
    //
//  NRCAppDelegate.h
//   LifeWatch
//
//  Created by Nelson Capes on 10/13/2015.
//  Copyright © 2015 Nelson Capes. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NRCAlertView.h"
extern NSString * const NRCAutoResetSwitch;

@interface NRCAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Here is the key being set in appDelegate.m:

```
    //
//  NRCAppDelegate.m
//  LifeWatch
//
//  Created by Nelson Capes on 10/13/2015.
//  Copyright © 2015 Nelson Capes. All rights reserved.
//

#import "NRCAppDelegate.h"
#import "NRCItemsViewController.h"
#import "NRCItemStore.h"
#import "NRCImageStore.h"
#import "NRCAppDelegate.h"
NSString * const NRCAutoResetSwitch = @"auto_reset_switch";
@class NRCItemsViewController;
@implementation NRCAppDelegate

+(void)initialize
{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSLog(@"defaults %@", [defaults
                           dictionaryRepresentation]);

    NSDictionary *factorySettings = @{NRCAutoResetSwitch : @"YES"};

    [defaults registerDefaults:factorySettings];

    NSLog(@"defaults %@", [defaults
                           dictionaryRepresentation]);

}
```

And here is the console log (part of it) after registering the defaults. Note **auto_reset_switch = YES"

```
2016-01-12 17:23:16.088 LifeWatch[373:20370] defaults {

    NSPersonNameDefaultDisplayNameOrder = 2;
    PKEnableStockholmSettings = 1;
    "auto_reset_switch" = YES;
    "com.apple.content-rating.AppRating" = 1000;
    "com.apple.content-rating.ExplicitBooksAllowed" = 1;
    "com.apple.content-rating.ExplicitMusicPodcastsAllowed" = 1;
    "com.apple.content-rating.MovieRating" = 1000;
    "com.apple.content-rating.TVShowRating" = 1000;
}
```

And here is the code to read the defaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSLog(@"defaults %@", [defaults
      dictionaryRepresentation]);
```

But now the console log shows "auto_reset_switch = 0":

```
NSPersonNameDefaultDisplayNameOrder = 2;
PKEnableStockholmSettings = 1;
"auto_reset_switch" = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want this to be a `BOOL` value instead of a string value, change `@"YES"` to `@YES`. This will make it a `BOOL` (wrapping in an `NSNumber` instead of an `NSString`.

```
NSDictionary *factorySettings = @{NRCAutoResetSwitch : @YES};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer on stackoverflow (I don't know how to link to it, so I am not trying to take credit for the answer. The code works well.

I think the example in my OP is wrong code.

```
    - (void)registerDefaultsFromSettingsBundle
{
    NSString *settingsBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"bundle"];
    if(!settingsBundle)
    {
        //NSLog(@"Could not find Settings.bundle");
        return;
    }

    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[settingsBundle stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Root.plist"]];
    NSArray *preferences = [settings objectForKey:@"PreferenceSpecifiers"];

    NSMutableDictionary *defaultsToRegister = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[preferences count]];
    for(NSDictionary *prefSpecification in preferences)
    {
        NSString *key = [prefSpecification objectForKey:@"Key"];
        if(key)
        {
            [defaultsToRegister setObject:[prefSpecification objectForKey:@"DefaultValue"] forKey:key];
        }
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultsToRegister];

}
```